# CXF wsdl2java - mapping namespaces and packages

Tags: java, mapping, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm using CXF's wsdl2java tool to create a java web service.
I have a wsdl file and a few XSD files and I know that it's possible to use a binding file to map namespaces and packages. My binding file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="SchemeA.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.package.a" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="SchemeB.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.package.b" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="SchemeC.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.package.c" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

My files:

- A.wsdl (imports all .xsd files)
- SchemeA.xsd
- SchemeB.xsd
- SchemeC.xsd

It works great for everything in this XSD schemes but not for wsdl's definition. I mean at the end my packages looks like this:

- com.test.package.a
- com.test.package.b
- com.test.package.c
- https.package_test_com.a.service

The last line bother me, and I would like it to look like this: com.test.package.a.service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding file is used by jaxb that manages bindings of paramater and responses but webservice is directly managed by cxf or jax-ws so you will need to specify this binding with -p option of wsdl2java as specified here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html